# Creating a popup and writing it as txt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, client-side

So, I have a rather odd question. I am writing client-side code (it HAS to be client side as a basic requirement) and need to create a popup which will display some code-generated output. Ideally, people should be able to copypaste this output in a txt file.

Now, when I create the window I can only write in it with `my_window.document.write("Blah blah blah")`. This means that I have to use html tags for things like going to the next line, and I basically have no easy way to tabulate. Since this is meant to be a data file, this is kind of annoying. Seeing how a browser is perfectly able to open a .txt file, isn't there a way to write to this document telling the browser to read it not as an .html, but as a .txt file? Thanks.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: As many as possible. But I'm already making use of HTML5 functionalities, so you can count IE8 and 9 out of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. What tells the browser the type of document is the content-type HTTP header, which is sent from the server.

But you can always dump your whole content into a `<pre>` element, or a `<textarea>`.

Comment: And making it a `textarea`, you can also automatically select all of its content (via JavaScript) to make it easier to copy and paste.

Comment: Well, sounds like an option. Would characters like \n and \t be accepted in such elements?